# Kendo Scheduler multiselect issue

Tags: json, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler, kendo-multiselect

We have Kendo scheduler, where we declaring categories. In event model we have `categories` field, which represents string array. 
In scheduler declaration we also have resources, such as this:

```
resources: [{
  field: "categories",
  dataSource: [{
    text: "",
    value: "red",
    color: "#FF0000"
  }, {
    text: "",
    value: "green",
    color: "#00FF00"
  }, {
    text: "blue",
    value: "blue",
    color: "#0000FF"
  }],
  multiple: true,
  title: "Category"
}],
```

In scheduler editing template we have

```
<label for="categories">Categories</label>
<select data-bind="value:categories" name="categories" id="categories" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select categories...">
</select>
```

and in scheduler `edit(e)` callback

```
var categ_editor = $("#categories").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataTextField: "value",
  dataValueField: "value",
  itemTemplate: '<div class="k-state-default"  style=\"width:100%; height:16px;\" ><div  style=\"background-color:#:data.color#; width:14px; height:14px;display:inline-block;\" ></div>&nbsp;#: data.value #</div>',
  tagTemplate: '<span class="k-state-default"><b   style=\"background-color:#:data.color#;\" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>&nbsp;#: data.value #</span>',

  dataSource: {
    data: [{
      text: "",
      value: "red",
      color: "#FF0000"
    }, {
      text: "",
      value: "green",
      color: "#00FF00"
    }, {
      text: "",
      value: "blue",
      color: "#0000FF"
    }]
  }
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

So, scheduler showing all good, and handle multiple values correct. 
But when I'm editing categories, scheduler sends whole `Category` object (with `text` and `color`) like this

```
"Categories": [{
  "text": "",
  "value": "red",
  "color": "#FF0000"
}, {
  "text": "",
  "value": "green",
  "color": "#00FF00"
}]
```

but correct JSON must be `"Categories":["red","green"]"`

How to fix this behavior?

Comment: Does SO have a code formatting?

Comment: Arman, SO doesn't allow for code formatting, as far as I know. You can format it using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [codePen](http://codepen.io/pen/), for example. It is an effort that ideally should be made by askers so that answerers can easily understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your multiselect data source contains collection of objects, therefore the value you get from multiselect will be in form of object. This is because `valuePrimitive` property, by default it is set to `false` so it will return `type` of data inside its data source which in this case is `object` instead of primitive value.

You should change it to `true`, to make it return just its value not the whole object. Your multiselect definition should be like this:

```
var categ_editor = $("#categories").kendoMultiSelect({
  valuePrimitive: true, // this prop you should add
  dataTextField: "value",
  dataValueField: "value",
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

See this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/eBuFO) to know the difference.

Comment: It works! Thanks, pal!
I've lost a week on this problem.